# News clustering program not displaying links in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, feed

I came across the following code in the book Programming collective intelligence called newsfeatures.py.

Here's the code:

```
import feedparser
import re
feedlist=['http://today.reuters.com/rss/topNews',
          'http://today.reuters.com/rss/domesticNews',
          'http://today.reuters.com/rss/worldNews',
          'http://hosted.ap.org/lineups/TOPHEADS-rss_2.0.xml',
          'http://hosted.ap.org/lineups/USHEADS-rss_2.0.xml',
          'http://hosted.ap.org/lineups/WORLDHEADS-rss_2.0.xml',
          'http://hosted.ap.org/lineups/POLITICSHEADS-rss_2.0.xml',
          'http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml',
          'http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/International.xml',
          'http://news.google.com/?output=rss',
          'http://feeds.salon.com/salon/news',
          'http://www.foxnews.com/xmlfeed/rss/0,4313,0,00.rss',
          'http://www.foxnews.com/xmlfeed/rss/0,4313,80,00.rss',
          'http://www.foxnews.com/xmlfeed/rss/0,4313,81,00.rss',
          'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss',
          'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_world.rss',
          'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_us.rss']
def stripHTML(h):
    p=''
    s=0
    for c in h:
        if c=='<': s=1
        elif c=='>':
            s=0
            p+=' '
        elif s==0: p+=c
    return p
def separatewords(text):
    splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
    return [s.lower( ) for s in splitter.split(text) if len(s)>3]
def getarticlewords( ):
    allwords={}
    articlewords=[]
    articletitles=[]
    ec=0
    # Loop over every feed
    for feed in feedlist:
        f=feedparser.parse(feed)
        # Loop over every article
        for e in f.entries:
            # Ignore identical articles
            if e.title in articletitles: continue
            # Extract the words
            txt=e.title.encode('utf8')+stripHTML(e.description.encode('utf8'))
            words=separatewords(txt)
            articlewords.append({})
            articletitles.append(e.title)
            # Increase the counts for this word in allwords and in articlewords
            for word in words:
                allwords.setdefault(word,0)
                allwords[word]+=1
                articlewords[ec].setdefault(word,0)
                articlewords[ec][word]+=1
            ec+=1
    return allwords,articlewords,articletitles
def makematrix(allw,articlew):
    wordvec=[]
    # Only take words that are common but not too common
    for w,c in allw.items( ):
        if c>3 and c<len(articlew)*0.6:
            wordvec.append(w)
    # Create the word matrix
    l1=[[(word in f and f[word] or 0) for word in wordvec] for f in articlew]
    return l1,wordvec
from numpy import *
def showfeatures(w,h,titles,wordvec,out='features.txt'):
    outfile=file(out,'w')
    pc,wc=shape(h)
    toppatterns=[[] for i in range(len(titles))]
    patternnames=[]
    # Loop over all the features
    for i in range(pc):
        slist=[]
        # Create a list of words and their weights
        for j in range(wc):
            slist.append((h[i,j],wordvec[j]))
        # Reverse sort the word list
        slist.sort( )
        slist.reverse( )
        # Print the first six elements
        n=[s[1] for s in slist[0:6]]
        outfile.write(str(n)+'\n')
        patternnames.append(n)
        # Create a list of articles for this feature
        flist=[]
        for j in range(len(titles)):
            # Add the article with its weight
            flist.append((w[j,i],titles[j]))
            toppatterns[j].append((w[j,i],i,titles[j]))
        # Reverse sort the list
        flist.sort( )
        flist.reverse( )
        # Show the top 3 articles
        for f in flist[0:3]:
            outfile.write(str(f)+'\n')
        outfile.write('\n')
    outfile.close( )
    # Return the pattern names for later use
    return toppatterns,patternnames
```

The usage is as follows:

```
>>> import newsfeatures
>>> allw,artw,artt= newsfeatures.getarticlewords( )
>>> artt[1]
u'Fatah, Hamas men abducted freed: sources'
```

As you can see, this line, produces the news headline.

```
>>> artt[1]
u'Fatah, Hamas men abducted freed: sources'
```

What I want to know is is there someway through which the program not only displays the headline, but also displays the source of the headline from the  `feedlist`.

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Modify the `getarticlewords` function and read the [`feedparser` documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/). There are a number of properties such as `feed.publisher` and `feed.title` and `entries[i].link` that likely contain what you want.

Comment: OMG, this bad code has *really* been in a book?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
articletitles.append(e.title)
```

in `getarticlewords()` with something like

```
articletitles.append(' '.join([e.title, ', from', feed]))
```